# Using a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a function get_word_codes so that it accepts a list of strings and returns a dictionary containing the strings as keys and a list of corresponding character codes as values. The following is one possible output:

```
words = ['yes', 'no']
codes = get_word_codes(words)
codes
{'yes': [121, 101, 115], 'no': [110, 111]}
```

As you can see, each letter has a number assigned to it. I want to do this using a dictionary comprehension and no loops. The only way I can see to do this is to hard code each number assigned to each letter. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use use `ord()` to get the character code.

Comment: How would I use ord() in a dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_word_codes(words):
    return {key : [ord(c) for c in key] for key in words}

words = ['yes', 'no']
codes = get_word_codes(words)
codes
```